# combine select id from other table with insert on single command

Tags: php, mysql

For inserting single row in database i have to get userId from other table, for doing this action i use `SELECT` nested insert.

but i dont know how can i get userId from `SELECT` section and put that on `INSERT` of `VALUES` , for example:

```
INSERT INTO notifications (
       userId ,
       type ,
       createdAt ,
       updatedAt
       SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'USERNAME'
) VALUES (?, ?, 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' , 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
```

for first column of notifications table i have too get userId from `SELECT` command, and put it on that,

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an insert select  eg:  this way

```
INSERT INTO notifications ( userId ,   type ,   createdAt ,  updatedAt) 
SELECT id, ? ,  'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' , 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
FROM users WHERE username = 'USERNAME'
```

Comment: Thanks to share your speciality